# What is the difference between "my english is getting improved." and "my english is improving"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences

I just wanna know what is the difference between these two sentences.
"My English is getting improved."
"My English is improving."
Are their meanings same or different.

Comment: Use _My English is improving_ (becoming better). _Getting improved_ or, better still _being improved_ means that something is making it better. It would be more natural to say something like "Talking with native speakers is improving my English."

Comment: *"My English is getting improved."* Without context, this sounds substandard. In this sense "getting" = becoming, and "improved" looks either (i) like an adjective. Compare *"My English is getting/becoming better."*.or (ii) like a passive - Compare *"My English is getting improved by constant practice."* ++* "My English is improving."* Without context, this sounds good. It is the present continuous form of the verb "to improve."